# Parameter Annotation does not read from my Testng.xml file

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testing, testng

i try to run my basic code with the `@Parameters({"browser"})` to take the Parameter name from my Testng.xml file , Gives Error that cant find the parameter

org.testng.TestNGException:
Parameter 'browser' is required by BeforeClass on method openBrowser but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.2\temp-testng-customsuite.xml

Expected to read from my Testng.xml file and run Successfully

Comment: Please share your full code. Only parameter and error trace is not understandable for answer the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.